# Collection to hold maximum number of running Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need a collection/bag (something) that will hold some maximum number of running `Task` objects. Adding a new running `Task` to the collection should block the calling thread (there are many threads trying to add a task so it should be thread safe) until there is an available slot for the new `Task` to be added if the maximum number of running tasks is reached. This is what I have so far and it is working fine.

Can you find any problems with this code? Or is there some built-in class that can handle this kind of task?

```
public class ConcurrentTaskLimiter
{
    public int MaxWorkingTasks { get; }
    private readonly Task[] _tasks;
    private readonly bool[] _finished;

    public ConcurrentTaskLimiter(int maxWorkingTasks)
    {
        MaxWorkingTasks = maxWorkingTasks;
        if ((1 <= maxWorkingTasks) == false)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxWorkingTasks), maxWorkingTasks, "Must be >= 1");
        _tasks = new Task[maxWorkingTasks];
        _finished = new bool[maxWorkingTasks];

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxWorkingTasks; i++)
        {
            _tasks[i] = Task.FromResult(0); // use this as finished tasks
            _finished[i] = true;
        }
    }

    public void BlockAdd(Task t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(t));

        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled
            || t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted
            || t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            return;

        lock (this)
        {
            int i;
            while (true)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < MaxWorkingTasks; i++)
                {
                    if (_finished[i])
                    {
                        _tasks[i] = t;
                        _finished[i] = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                i = Task.WaitAny(_tasks);
                _finished[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have described here is a Producer- Consumer relationship. .Net has a `BlockingCollection` that performs exactly what you are trying to create here

```
public BlockingCollection(
    IProducerConsumerCollection<T> collection,
    int boundedCapacity
)
```

> You could use a ConcurrentBag as the underlying store or any ConcurrentCollection of your choice and the `boundedCapacity`can be the maximum number of Tasks that can be added to the collection. An example usage is

```
BlockingCollection<int> messages = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentBag<int>(), 10);
```

Comment: I thought of BlockingCollection<T> but in this case how am I going to remove the finished tasks efficiently. On every Add I have to .ToArray() on the blocking collection WaitAny(arrayTask), and then instantiate a new BlockingCollection<T> with the finished task removed, and add the new one added. This seems as a lot of unnecessary operations just for the sake of using the BlockingCollection. Or am I missing some obvious solution?

Comment: @MihailShiahkov I will post an example of how to use the same blocking collection as a producer and a consumer shortly

Comment: The quotes are misleading. It looks like the OP has said that. I suggest not using it for your own words.

Comment: Will update my review @t3chb0t

Comment: I didn't mean removing everything :-o just the quote formattings where applicable :-)